# Ruby on Rails 4 filtering includes Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm new on Rails, and I'm trying to do some queries, but I'm failing. I have two ActiveRecord::Base, as follows:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end
```

and

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
end
```

I want to show every row from A. Inside these rows, every row from B (related to that A), where B has some arbitrary date (passed as argument).

I've already tried to use scope, joins, includes, merges, but nothing seems to work. 
I want all A's, with A.bs returning only Bs from that specific date.
In many cases, A doesn't have Bs for the particular date, and even so I want A returned, with A.bs empty.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.includes` to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which includes the records in A (left) even if there is no match in B (right).

```
@a = A.includes(:bs).where(bs: { due_at: Date.yesterday }).find(params[:id])
@bs = @a.bs # will use the eager loaded collection
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Comment: Note that the same applies even if you use `.all` or some other options to fetch A.

Comment: It didn't work. The result was the list of As that have Bs in that date. I want all As, if they have or no Bs in that date. @a comes empty if there isn't Bs in due date.

Comment: Try running the query in the rails console and check the SQL generated

Comment: Your code generate the SQL:    SELECT * FROM as LEFT OUTER JOIN bs ON bs.a_id = a.id WHERE b.due_date = 2016-01-25    .What I want is:     
SELECT * FROM as LEFT OUTER JOIN bs ON bs.a_id = a.id AND b.due_date = 2016-01-25    , I don't want a where, I want to add a condition to ON.